# Two iterations of the same column in R

Tags: r, for-loop, iteration

The goal is to compare the second row with the first row and repeat this. My strategy is to perform two separate iterations on the same column vector in R.

Here is the code:

For the test data, the length of the data is 50

```
dat <- rnorm(50)        
dat <- data.frame(dat)
```

## function

```
cv2 = function(a) {

  for(i in 1:nrow(a)) { 

  for(j in 1:nrow(a)) {

  iplus1 = next(a[j])

  return((2*(abs((a[i])-(iplus1)))) / ((a[i])+(iplus1)))

}}}
```

The output should create a statistic with a range between 0-2, and be of length equal to 49. So far the return of this function is NULL. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Not quite sure what you are trying to do, but the `return` will terminate the function in the first pass through the loop. If you were to use loops (likely not the best approach) you should *accumulate* what you are trying to compute and then return it after the loop.

Comment: Why do you think that the range of the computed numbers lies in 0-2?

Comment: The 0-2 range is biologically specific when sub-setting the data by the group. output  <- with(data, tapply(data$number, data$group, cv2))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The described computation is really a computation on vectors. In base R, you could do it like this:

```
cv2 = function(a){
  n <- length(a)
  2*abs((a[-1]-a[-n])/(a[-1]+a[-n]))
}
```

and then call it like `cv2(dat[1,])` if you want to feed it a column of a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of `dplyr` package you can do try this:

```
> library(dplyr)
> x <- rnorm(50)
> df <- data.frame(x)
> output <- df %>%
+     mutate(y = lag(x)) %>%
+     mutate(result = (2*abs(x-y)) / (x+y))
```

Which would give you a result like this:

```
           x            y        result
1  -0.208826981           NA            NA
2  -0.701317391 -0.208826981 -1.082225e+00
3  -0.740003385 -0.701317391 -5.368131e-02
4  -1.162325354 -0.740003385 -4.440052e-01
5  -0.133625594 -1.162325354 -1.587560e+00
6  -1.115008292 -0.133625594 -1.571930e+00
7   0.579094801 -1.115008292 -6.322301e+00
8  -1.194556141  0.579094801 -5.763647e+00
9  -0.131487021 -1.194556141 -1.603370e+00
10  0.646124908 -0.131487021  3.021977e+00
11 -0.551389477  0.646124908  2.528124e+01
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the formula, but in `baseR` you can use `sapply`

```
dat <- data.frame(col1 = rnorm(50), col2 = rnorm(50) )
dat$res <- sapply(1:nrow(dat), function(t) 2*(abs(dat[t,1]-dat[t,2])) / (dat[t,1]+dat[t,2]))

head(dat)
     col1        col2         res
1 -0.62036668  0.45018710 -12.5814602
2  0.04211587 -0.01855983   5.1516048
3 -0.91092165 -0.31806837  -0.9647813
4  0.15802877 -0.92936215  -2.8195096
5 -0.65458464 -1.48746031  -0.7776454
6  1.76728727 -1.07519230   8.2141315
```